# Streaming dynamically created ZIP file with Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, java-stream

I have a question regarding dynamically creating and streaming ZIP files. I have multiple large files stored on remote HTTP servers (for example Amazon S3).

Now I want the user to download let's say 100 files as one ZIP file.

I could download all 100 files, zip them and stream them to the user, but that would be wasting lots of resources. So my approach is **download the first file, stream it to the user, download the next file, stream it to the user** and so on.

This is the test code:

```
public class TestController extends Controller {
  public Result test() throws Exception {
        InputStream is = getDynamicStreamSomewhere();

        response().setContentType("application/zip");
        response().setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=test.zip");

        return ok(is);

    }

    private InputStream getDynamicStreamSomewhere() throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos);

        String url1 = "http://www.example.com/largefile1.bin";
        String url2 = "http://www.example.com/largefile2.bin";

        ZipEntry entry1 = new ZipEntry("file1.bin");
        zos.putNextEntry(entry1);
        URL website = new URL(url2);
        InputStream in = website.openStream();
        IOUtils.copy(in, zos);
        in.close();
        zos.closeEntry();

        ZipEntry entr2 = new ZipEntry("file2.bin");
        zos.putNextEntry(entr2);
        URL websitea = new URL(url1);
        InputStream ina = websitea.openStream();
        IOUtils.copy(ina, zos);
        ina.close();
        zos.closeEntry();

        return new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
    }

}
```

But as far as I debugged it, that does not really stream file by file but download everything and then stream it to the user.

What I am missing is something like flushing the output buffer to the user after every file (or maybe after each 4KB block).

I know how to do it with Java servlets, but not with Play Framework. Any help is appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Please put the code in here.

Comment: I linked it to the github GIST where it is formatted. Why should I copy it to the comments? What would be the advantage? Thank you

Comment: Put it into the question, not the comments. We need to see the code to help. Depending on other sites isn't the usual way to go here.

Comment: okay, I inlined the source code.

Comment: @schube I'm sorry for necroposting, but did you try this: https://github.com/tsabirgaliev/zip ?

Comment: @Tair Thanks for the hint, I was not aware of that. I had implemented it like my original sourcecode. It is not streaming, but it works in everyday usage.